# How to navigate without grids

Tags: navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What would be the best way to have actual navigation in free space for ROS. I mean so that the planner will **not** rely on a grid map.

Thanks :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267525/how-to-navigate-without-grids/) by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) on ROS Answers with karma: 862 on 2017-07-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Exists OMPL (open motion planning library) that allows to select from a variety of planning methods that can or not really on grid maps, such as CHOMP or RRT.

http://wiki.ros.org/ompl

---

Originally posted by [Leo Campos](https://answers.ros.org/users/31372/leo-campos/) with karma: 41 on 2017-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) on 2017-07-28**:
That is exactly what I was looking for. thanks :)